# How to click one of the options listed in the drop down menu in hand coded UI testing?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

```
        UITestControl uiLinkAboutus = new UITestControl(_bw);
        uiLinkAboutus.TechnologyName = "Web";
        uiLinkAboutus.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Image");
        uiLinkAboutus.SearchProperties.Add("TagName", "IMG");
        uiLinkAboutus.SearchProperties.Add("Alt", "Open Menu");
        Mouse.Click(uiLinkAboutus);
```

/* Upon execution, the drop down button is clicked but the option listed below is not clicked. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stead of searching for an image, search for the list or dropdown control using a wpfCombobox, winCombobox or HtmlComboBox control. There you set the selectedItem property to the value you want. that is the most robust way of selecting an item in the UI. so e.g. : 
`ApplicationUnderTest aut = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(@"yourapp.exe");  
WpfComboBox cbBox = new WpfComboBox(aut); 
cbBox.SearchProperties.Add(WpfComboBox.PropertyNames.AutomationId,"cmbCountries");//AutomationId == xName roperty 
cbBox.SelectedItem = "your value";`